# Standard approach for controlling Amplifier?

Tags: linux, audio, gpio

Currently I am working on a custom board having TPA3118D audio amplifier. The amplifier has 3 GPIO pins (Mute, Enable,Fault) which are controlled from the processor. We are able to hear the audio once I make the enable high from Linux running in the processor. I was thinking to automate this process by telling the Linux to make the enable pin high during the booting. This is where I am having the confusion. Is this the right approach? Is it okay to enable the amplifier as soon as the hardware starts or the Amplifier should be enabled only when we are playing the audio?

I would like to understand the standard approach for controlling Amplifier. How is the enable pin handled? Do we keep the Amplifier always ON or enable it during playback only?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No, it’s bad idea. First of all, it might be too high volume or glitches on audio channel that may damage ears for real (remember the case with high volume in some Nokia? phones). Second, it’s not a business of this hardware to decide. Consider resource provider-consumer scheme: consumer should control resource. But in your case you are suggesting the opposite.